# ¿Formulario dinámico?

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

estoy tratando de generar un formulario dinámico, donde los inputs se generan dependiendo de una consulta a MySQL, y dependiendo del número de resultados es la cantidad de Input Fields que genera el formulario.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo es que puedo procesar todos estos inputs generados dinámicamente, para introducirlos a la base de datos uno por uno, sin importar el número de input fields que se hayan generado en el formulario?

No se si se le llame "formulario dinámico" a esto, si alguien pudiera corregirme en esto para investigar un poco más en el foro y google se los agradeceré, tal vez el problema radique en que no se como llamarle a esto para poder encontrar una respuesta certera.

Solamente estoy utilizando php y mysql, nada de JS.

Saludos y de antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

espero que sea lo que buscas,
para algo asi podrias hacer algo asi:

```
id | name | city
------------------
1  | n1   | c1
2  | n2   | c2
3  | n3   | c3
4  | n4   | c4
```

imaginemos que tienes esta tabla

podrias usar MySQLi extension y crear algo asi:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = 'c7'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
     // no encontrado.
} else {
    // hacer otra cosa.
}
$mysqli->close();
```

como vez en la primera linea miramos si existe un valor en MySQl ,si quieres leer mas acerca de esta funcionalidad en Mysql te recomiendo leer esto:

[select en mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

ahora que sabes que existe el valor que buscas, podrias ejecutar algunos script js desde PHP de esta manera :

```
  echo "script> console.log('hola');";
```

pero en vez de  ejecutar eso podrias crear algo asi:

```css
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
container.appendChild(input); // put it into the DOM
```

aqui estoy usando :**document.createElement** mas info aqui:
[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

y listo :) el codigo anterior deberias agregarlo en tu if cuando validas tu busqueda de los datos en php y solo asocias cada name del input con el valor que quieres que se muestre en el.

**si tienes alguna duda con el codigo comenta.**

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por tu interés en ayudarme, tal vez me expresé mal, pero si sé generar los input field dinamicamente según el resultado de la consulta a mysql, lo que no se es como procesar ese formulario para insertar los nuevos datos a mysql independientemente de si el formulario generó solamente 3 input fields o 999 input fields. No sé si me doy a explicar....

Comment: Supongo que se puede utilizar alguna función tipo "foreach" o algo así, más no estoy seguro si es lo ideal

Comment: mm puedes agregar tu codigo para darme una mejor idea y asi poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Creas una tabla dynamicForms que tenga ID, descripción , nombreTabla,sp_alta, sp_modificacion

Otra tabla dynamicFormsParams que contendrá todos los parámetros de entrada con su orden en el sp ,del sp de alta y de modificación.

Que contenga ID,idForm, nombreParam., numeroOrden,

Ya con esto desde PHP recibes un JSON que contendrá :

Un Array del tipo dynamicFormsParams, con su respectivo valor que le dio el usuario.
Un objeto del tipo DynamicForm con el cual obtendrás el nombre del sp para modificar/insertar.

Ya con esto simplemente llamas al sp que te llegó en el objeto DynamicForm y le pones los parámetros con el orden Recorriendo el Arrau DynamicFormsParams